# Is alpha induced angle real on 3D wing or just math concept?

Tags: aerodynamics

Does alpha induced angle/"effective airflow" really exist in real life on 3D wing or this is just mathematical concept for calculate induced drag?

(same as lifting line theory-circulation theory is just math concept for calcualte lift ,but everyone knows that airflow dont move around wing in circle...)

Question is ,if I put AoA-sensor infront of leading edge at same position at 2D and 3D wing,will be values different or equal?

(theory tell us that angle (A) at my picture below must be less on 3D wing than 2D wing...)[image]

(in my home made wind tunnel ,I cant see difference when I put visual AoA indicator infront of leading edge at  2D compare to  3D wing..so this is reason why I ask is this real thing(maybe angle is too small to see) or just math concept...all this mess with questions about induced drag on this forum ,starts when I do this experiments..)

[image]

[image]

here is exampels of visual AoA indicators:[video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vgw8AawCuYM)     [video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ubx5S8rzl7s)

Comment: Congratulations for your AoA vane on the model airplane. Enjoyed watching the videos!

Comment: This is not my work I just put link of video..but yes nice to watch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. Summary

Induced angle of attack is technically a mathematical concept. You can't measure it directly via flow sensors [from an isolated wing]. However, it is extremely useful in understanding and predicting the production of induced drag.

Just like Newton's theory of gravity is a mathematical abstraction; but, if it helps you in understanding and predicting outcomes, you might as well accept it as real. Read the following subsections if you want to understand the [potential flow aerodynamic modeling](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/75506/what-is-the-role-of-a-bound-vortex) a bit better.

**EDIT**: provided that you have an extremely long wing (and tunnel width) to call 2D section, and provided you have a corresponding high aspect ratio wing to call 3D section, the difference in AOA measured at the same chordwise location should converge to the induced AOA.

### 2. Lifting-Line

Induced angle of attack comes from an aerodynamic modeling method, called [Lifting Line Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-line_theory), which approximates the whole wing as one single bound vortex line that changes in vorticity strength across the span. The change in vorticity is shed via trailing vortices across the span.

Since [vorticity induces cross-flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law#Aerodynamics_applications), this model predicts net *downwash* (downward airflow) at every point along this vortex line. And since the wing is just a line, we can neatly separate out the free-stream velocity, which may have a **free-stream angle of attack**, or geometric angle of attack, against the line, and a downwash velocity that modifies the flow incidence, which we can call **induced angle of attack**.

[image: Lifting Line]

*Image ref: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Lifting-Line-Theory-Scheme-Epps-2010_fig1_273450664*

This simplified model predicts surprisingly accurate lift for straight, mid to high aspect ratio wing, in low subsonic flight. It also predicts a new kind of drag, called *induced drag*, which is totally absent in 2D subsonic [potential] flow.

Now, my question is, is any wing a single vortex line? Of course not. It's a model that gives very useful engineering results. The immediate shortcoming of the model is that it doesn't predict the flow field around the wing well, at all. How can it? It's a line!

### 3. Lifting-Surface

We can do better by approximating the whole wing as a lifting surface (or its cousin [vortex-lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_lattice_method)), with the whole surface producing and shedding vorticity. This model is able to predict the flow field near the wing much better, by producing a different value of downwash at every spanwise *and* chordwise point. In front of the wing, there will be upwash. **So if you measure flow incidence in front of the wing, you will measure higher incidence than the free-stream one.**

[image: Lifting surface]

*Image ref: Drela, Flight Vehicle Aerodynamics*

At this point, you should realize that the *induced angle of attack* is no more (because there is different downwash at every chordwise point). But for the same high aspect ratio, straight tapered wing, both lifting-line and lifting surface will agree on prediction of lift and induced drag.

So once again, is a wing a flat surface of vorticity? Of course not. Wing has thickness that lifting surface doesn't handle, and nor does it predict boundary layer.

Comment: This picture was stolen from the book "Flight Vehicle Aerodynamics" by the heli-air.net site admin. On top of that, Almost all the content on that website appears to be stolen contents from other sources. I would like to kindly request this REF to be removed from the heli-air.net and give rightful credit to the correct source which is https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/flight-vehicle-aerodynamics

Comment: @m2as3registeredservicesohmone Thanks. But you do know that your comment here will not be heard by the guys at heli-air.net, right?

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement @JZYL. I don't mind me not being heard. Even I'm heard stealers are stealers and they gonna probability keep stealing others work anyway. On the personal level I have a great respect to the person who actually wrote that book and I have used the Latex package which was used to generate these figures. I know how hard it is to create these figures and how much thought the original Author might have put in to these. Thats the only reason for my request.

Comment: @JZYL so induced alpha angle dont exist in reality and my AoA sensor will show equal angles for 2d and 3D wing.. Your answer is opposite from m2as3registeredservices ohmone..How do you comment his answer?

Comment: @ROTOR Please read the bolded part in section 3

Comment: And I think we've already addressed this in our long winded comments last time: just because you've made the width of the tunnel same as the wing span, doesn't mean you're measuring 2D section.

Comment: My question was compare upwash angle at  2D vs 3D wing,not compare upwash angle to freestream..

Comment: @ROTOR If you have an uber long wing span, and a wind tunnel to go with it, then yes, you should measure differences. The difference should converge to induced AOA as well, provided that the 3D wing itself has high aspect ratio.

Comment: I dont understand why I need extremely long wing/tunnel width to meassure this differences?When you say extremely long ,you mean on infinity or Nasa Ames biggiest wind tunnel in the world will be enough ?

Comment: How else do you ensure you're measuring 2D without 3D effect? You can use corrections, but that's based on theory you're trying to test...

Comment: Yes I understand that,but if for example, rectangular wing is long 2m and "small" tunnel is also 2m width for 2D test(walls touch tips),and now we put this 2m wing at 30m wind tunnel for 3D test,will this be enough to meassure difference?

Comment: 2m wing in 30m tunnel will definitely have less interference effects...But that's probably not what you're asking...

Comment: Yes for sure, my tunnel is only 50x50cm...

Comment: @JZYL "_EDIT:provided that you have an extremely long wing (and tunnel width)_" You mean infinitely long?

Answer (score 2):

> Does alpha induced angle/"effective airflow" really exist in real life on 3D wing or this is just mathematical concept for calculate induced drag?

This induced angle really exist in real life on 3D wing. The physical reason why (what caused that induced angle) we see this induced angle is not the vorticity of the flow field though.

> (same as lifting line theory-circulation theory is just math concept for calcualte lift ,but everyone knows that airflow dont move around wing in circle...)

I would not overgeneralize it as such myself. If you try to understand the derivation of lifting line theory I think you will be in a better position to appreciate it. Also, lift-circulation relationship comes from the Kutta-Joukowsky Theorem and not from the lifting line theory.

Also, the circulation is a generalized concept to indicate the strength of a point vortex. The general definition of the circulation is the integral of tangential velocity over any contour containing a point vortex. This **DOES NOT** mean airflow move around the wing in circles.

> Question is ,if I put AoA-sensor in front of leading edge at same position at 2D and 3D wing,will be values different or equal?

Different values. In the 3D wing, the angle indicated should be lesser than that of the 2D wing.

> (in my home made wind tunnel ,I cant see difference when I put visual AoA indicator in-front of leading edge at 2D compare to 3D wing..so this is reason why I ask is this real thing(maybe angle is too small to see) or just math concept...all this mess with questions about induced drag on this forum ,starts when I do this experiments..)

I for one would love to see some pictures of your home-made wind tunnel and experimental set-up.

PS1: This [video from Doug McLean](https://youtu.be/QKCK4lJLQHU?t=1710) might be of help to understand it little better

PS2: As a completely general advise, Unfortunately, Its a little difficult subject to follow "Correctly", and as in any other scientific discipline, the problems and solutions tend to lie in different places than the majority of the people think where they are; so at least in a long run, probably it's a good idea to learn at least the basics enough to validate what's thrown your way. There are few very good *free online* courses on [edx.org](https://www.edx.org/)

Comment: @m2as3registerdservicesohmen,so you say that alpha induced angle exist in reality and we can prove it  with AoA sensors...1)What is physical reason what cause alpha induced angle/shift in effective airflow  2)How do you comment JZYL answer,your answer is opposite from him

Comment: I add picture concept and explantion

Comment: With walls (2D test) I always get higher lift and DRAG than when I remove walls(3D test).So 3D wing(test without walls) I always get smaller lift and SMALLER DRAG then 2d test,for same AoA in both tests...Pressure loss on 3D wing outboard parts is so much,that lift and drag always drops.TESTO 510 always show significantly smaller pressure differential on wingtips at 3D wing,what is very logical because there is so much air LEAKAGE on it...